# Deja Dup restore lost last modified dates of files

Tags: restore, deja-dup, duplicity

After a new system install, I used [Deja Dup](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/deja-dup.1.html) to restore my files from a previous backup.

I recovered my files, however I lost in the process all the dates of the files and folders. All of them have been reset at the restoration date (yesterday). There is for me valuable information in the dates, which allows me to search recently modified files, files modified in 2012, etc.

Have I overlooked an option in the restoration process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by using the related command line utility behind Deja Dup: [duplicity](https://nongnu.org/duplicity/index.html).

I tried with duplicity 0.7.18 (the one provided in the official repos), tried different protocols, but still encountered the bug.

I finally installed a snap of duplicity 0.8.07 and it worked with the command

```
snap run duplicity restore --ssh-askpass --no-encryption --numeric-owner -t my-time-stamp sftp://my.login@my.location .
```